# 12/24 volt system. With diagram

Tags: wiring

Please review diagram. A simple basic system to provide 12 or 24 volts. SPDT switch will activate either the 12 or 24 V system.
The solenoid is used in the 24 V system because of the high current load of the winch.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram makes little sense as it is just lines and boxes. Research the correct symbols and redraw.

Comment: It appears that the negative terminals of the two batteries are permanently connected together - you can't get 24 V that way.  You may get lots of smoke, flame, or spraying acid when you close the 24V relay.

Comment: @CatNap what is your question?

Comment: That diagram is not going to work for you. This is a hard problem actually, since you have 3 switches you must make and break *in a particular order* and if you botch the order you get a face full of acid.

Answer (score 3):

A 160 A DC, DPDT switch may be used.

[image]

The batteries get connected in series for 24 V and in parallel for 12 V.